# Firebase query filter and select

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My data is like this:

```
"orders":
{
  "-L6ue92e4DQ7Mm-veRxN" : {
    "customer" : {
      "address" : {
        "country" : "",
        "postCode" : "CB2 3AW",
        "street" : "86 High Street"
      },
      "email" : "poo@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Pooh"
    },
    "deliveryMethod" : "fastest",
    "ingredients" : [ {
      "Ingredient" : "cheese",
      "Price" : 0.3,
      "Quantity" : 1
    }, {
      "Ingredient" : "meat",
      "Price" : 1,
      "Quantity" : 2
    } ],
    "price" : 6.3
  },

  "-L6ueB632CCTKhGbbGLC" : {
    "customer" : {
      "address" : {
        "country" : "",
        "postCode" : "CB2 3AW",
        "street" : "86 High Street"
      },
      "email" : "poo@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Pooh"
    },
    "deliveryMethod" : "fastest",
    "ingredients" : [ {
      "Ingredient" : "relish",
      "Price" : 0.15,
      "Quantity" : 1
    }, {
      "Ingredient" : "bacon",
      "Price" : 0.4,
      "Quantity" : 1
    }, {
      "Ingredient" : "meat",
      "Price" : 1,
      "Quantity" : 2
    } ],
    "price" : 6.55
  },

  "-L6ueD9A2VuZUrM1hAFf" : {
    "customer" : {
      "address" : {
        "country" : "",
        "postCode" : "CB2 3AW",
        "street" : "86 High Street"
      },
      "email" : "poo@gmail.com",
      "name" : "Pooh"
    },
    "deliveryMethod" : "fastest",
    "ingredients" : [ {
      "Ingredient" : "meat",
      "Price" : 1,
      "Quantity" : 2
    }, {
      "Ingredient" : "salad",
      "Price" : 0.2,
      "Quantity" : 1
    } ],
    "price" : 6.2
  }
}
```

I want to select the orders where the email address matches my criteria and then only return the ingredients node.

I can filter on email and then get the entire orders node like this:

```
db.ref('orders')
        .orderByChild("customer/email")
        .equalTo(req.query.email)
        .once('value')
```

and that returns the filtered orders

but equalTo returns a Query. ref is a reference to the location of that query. And so I was expecting to be able to do this:

```
db.ref('orders')
        .orderByChild("customer/email")
        .equalTo(req.query.email)
        .ref
        .child('ingredients')
        .once('value')
```

but that returns null. As I am new to this (moving from SQL) I am not sure what to do. I could probably do something in the .then of the .once but that seems inefficient. Have I gone about this the wrong way?

Also, do I have to do the orderByChild? Can I not just filter on the email without ordering?

This is all part of a React SPA web app.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question(s).  It sounds like you have the start a working solution, but you're just wondering why you can't do things another way?

Comment: @Doug, yes I can make it work for me by returning the whole order node and then on the client just using the part I want but I would rather not send all that info over the wire, it's a waste.

Comment: @Peter, yes I can do it this way, still seems strange that I can't query on a parent node effectively, ie I want all the ingredient child nodes where it's parent has a specific attribute.
Also, I don't fully understand why the chain doesn't work. The interface guide shows .ref as a reference to a query. And according to that guide, the reference has a number of methods including child which again returns a Reference, which has another method of once. Where is this logic wrong?

Comment: you filter the parent doing this orderByKey().equalTo(...) @user2047485 The answer below is the recommended way and it makes it easier to be able to get the values using the email that you provide. Also it is better not to nest the database, should be flat, please read this: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html. Also please upvote the answer and mark as correct since it helped, thank you!

Comment: surely with that structure you would use customerid in the order not customer email? Then I would have to get customerid by querying customers on the email followed by getting orders using that customerid...
I think the answer is that I cannot select child nodes as a collection (ie ingredients node on every order in this case), right? I can select a specific ingredients node or I can select all children of a path (ie in this case orders) and once I do that I can only return the full objects

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the structure of your database depending on what your queries are going to be, this wont work:

```
 db.ref('orders')
    .orderByChild("customer/email")
    .equalTo(req.query.email)
    .ref
    .child('ingredients')
    .once('value')
```

also you can only use one query (one `orderByChild()`), and yes when filter you have to use orderbychild.

You have different queries like this:

```
orderByChild("customer").equalTo(namehere);
orderByChild("time").startAt(5).endAt(5\uf8ff);
```

Try this database:

```
customers
  customerid
     email:poo@gmail.com
     name:Pooh
     address  
      country:countryname
      postCode"CB2 3AW
      street:86 High Street
   customerid2
         /*some data here for other customer */
```

---

```
orders
  orderid
    customeremail: poo@gmail.com
    deliveryMethod:fastest
    Ingredient: cheese
    Price: 0.3
    Quantity : 1
  orderid1
    customeremail: poo@gmail.com
    deliveryMethod:fastest
    Ingredient : meat
    Price: 1
    Quantity: 2
```

Now you can do this:

```
firebase.database().ref().child("orders").orderByChild("customeremail").equalTo("poo@gmail.com").once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
snapshot.forEach(function(child) { 
var ingredients=child.val().Ingredient;

   )};
 )};
```